# How to rotate display to portrait mode from landscape in android via buld.prop or something else?

Tags: android, orange-pi

I have Orange pi 4 LTE with Andoid 8.1 from Orangepi.org, 7" external display with touchscreen connected via HDMI to Pi.
I tried change to portrait mode with Playmarket apps but it didnt help. Tried to change /system/build.pro "ro.sf.hwrotation" to 0, but it makes portrait mode in landscape (with blackbars).
180 makes same resuts. 270 makes normal landscape
Does anyone know how to rotate to normal portrait mode?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfr8g.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvKFS.jpg)

I tried change to portrait mode with Playmarket apps but it didnt help. Tried to change /system/build.pro "ro.sf.hwrotation" to 0, but it makes portrait mode in landscape (with blackbars).